# How to redirect user in React Context using React Router Dom outside Router component

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I have a dashboard and Authentication Context in it, my entire app is wrapped in the Auth Context, it's something like this

main.jsx file

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <RouterProvider router={AllRoutes} />
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </Suspense>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I'm using React Router 6.8.1 which provides `RouterProvider` component.
In the AuthContext I have a check for the token if it's in LocalStorage or not:

```
const authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
if (!authToken) {
  // I want to redirect the user to login page
}
```

I can't use `useNavigate` hook, since it's out of `Router` component, and also `redirect("/login")` is not working there, and `useHistory` hook & `Redirect` component are all removed in the react router 6.0.0.

I wrapped `AuthContextProvider` component with `Router` component, but it's not working.

How should I redirect users then?